# Should you always refer to local class variables with "this"

Tags: c#

In C# you can refer to values in a class using the 'this' keyword.

```
class MyClass
{
    private string foo;

    public string MyMethod()
    {
        return this.foo;
    }
}
```

While I presume the answer will likley be user preference, is it best practice to use the this keyword within a class for local values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the spirit of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I would say this is not a particularly useful practice in general. Almost any use of `this` can be shortened to an equivalent expression by just removing the `this`.

One exception is if you have a local parameter which happens to have the same name as another class member; in that case you must distinguish between the two with `this`. But this is a situation you can easily avoid, by simply renaming the parameter.

Comment: Another exception is using an extension method within the class that has been extended. You are required to use this.

Comment: That's true. But if you control the class, you might want to think twice about using extension methods and just use class methods instead. And if you don't control the class, you can't run into this (no pun intended) situation.

Comment: ^^ good point. The only exception is if you're using extension methods which accept *interfaces* as the parameter, in which case extension methods are your only option :-)

Comment: This is a misrepresentation of DRY. DRY refers to code reuse, not removing syntax for the sake of saving a few keystrokes.

Comment: I don't think it's a misrepresentation. "this" isn't merely a few keystrokes -- it's a syntactically meaningful construct whose use is generally redundant. From WP: "DRY is not about just avoiding code duplication, but more generally about avoiding multiple [...] ways to express [...] knowledge".

Answer (score 5):

I use the `this` keyword  almost only when some member is hiding another, and when I need to pass the current class instance to a method for example:

```
class Employee
{
    private string name;
    private string address;

    // Pass the current object instance to another class:
    public decimal Salary 
    {
        get { return SalaryInfo.CalculateSalary(this); }
    }


    public Employee(string name, string address) 
    {
        // Inside this constructor, the name and address private fields
        // are hidden by the paramters...
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say it depends on personal preference for your own coding and on the team/company coding standards for your code at work. Personally, I try to keep both personal and "professional" coding standards the same--it reduces confusion, etc.

I prefer to use "this" on all class-level functions and variables. By using "this" you can immediately tell if the item is a class member or not. Also,I prefer to use "base" on members belonging to any base classes.  It's not necessary, but it helps readability, esp if someone unfamiliar with your code is reading it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this syntax. As the classes get larger and the functions get more complex, it is convenient to be able to read a variable name and know whether or not its an instance var without having to reference another part of the code.

Edit: I realize that if one is having trouble keeping track of variables, then it is probably time to refactor. This is fine in the abstract. So then to clarify: in the case where classes and their relationships *aren't* simple (and surely they exist) or in code where people have not refactored or followed good guidelines for keeping parameter names different from instance vars, I'll say (imho!) that using 'this' isn't a bad idea for clear code.

Comment: This is a personal preference, but IMO, if you need to use "this." as a crutch for understanding a complex class, it might be time to think about refactoring that class.

Answer (score 1):

I never use it. Mostly, it doesn't matter if a variable is a member or not. Keep your methods small enough that it's no problem to remember which variables are locals, and you won't mave so much trouble remembering which are members.

I use "_" as a prefix for member variables, as it is easy to ignore. But this means there will never be a collision with a local or parameter, so this. is not necessary.

My attitude may be "colored" by the fact that I use ReSharper, whose "color identifiers" mode makes it easier for me to see what's what.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - it's very much a preference thing. Of course, many companies enforce a set of coding style guidelines that either require `this` before any instance member, or require that it not appear. (Does anyone know what the Microsoft FxCop rules for the .NET framework are?)

Personally, I prefer to have `this` appear before any property, method or field that belongs to an instance. It makes it easier for me to distinguish where it belongs:

- A member of an instance of the class (prefixed with `this`)
- A static class member (which I prefix with the name of the class)
- A local scope variable (no prefix)

It's more important to me to be able to read my code less ambiguously, than it is to save the 5 characters of `this.`. For instance, I immediately know that I need to `dispose()` all the local-scope items that were opened in this scope, and I won't confuse them with the instance-members that shouldn't be disposed. Heck, just for extra laziness points, I use `this.` as a quick way to access the intellisense list of member of the instance members.

Comment: I too prefer using the 'this', 'base' and class name for statics throughout - a habit developed working inside Microsoft on projects where FxCop rules enforced it - looking at other people's code these days, members seem 'naked' without them to me.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, yes! In languages where it's not necessary, no. Some people do it to make the "memberness" visible to someone reading the code - but your IDE should be able to take care of that by highlighting it.

When VS 2010 comes out, my plan for world peace is to write an extension for the WPF code editor that displays `this.` in front of every reference to a member variable than doesn't already have that prefix. Then those who need that reminder will no longer need to type it, and those who don't like it can simply not install my extension and can freely delete any unnecessary `this.` prefixes they see.

Comment: +1 on your extension, assuming it's not already in ReSharper at the time.

Comment: I give those guys about a week after the first VS2010 beta! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should always include it if you are specifically referring to the class variable.

The reason for this is if you later on add in a local variable of the same name, you will need to rename all the class variables with `this.` so why not save your future self some time and hassle?